Implementing the E91 Protocol in Quantum Computing
I am currently studying quantum key distribution and I am particularly interested in the E91 protocol
I am trying to implement a simple scheme of this protocol for educational purposes. and i am having trouble understanding how to detect an eavesdropper, Eve, when Alice and Bob are trying to exchange keys for secure communication1.
Could anyone provide a step-by-step guide or a simple code snippet on how to implement the E91 protocol? Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance

You can refer this link for the implementation of E91 protocol
https://quantumeon.com/demos/cryptography-code/e91-protocol/
